# Where did Kraglin get a fin from?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

There's a scene in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* where Kraglin, Yondu's ravager friend played by Sean Gunn, is seen wearing Yondu's experimental red fin, and controlling the arrow.

But that doesn't make any sense to me, because

> Yondu was shown to have been cremated with the experimental fin still on his head. The fin definitely disintegrated too; it was very clearly shown to be destroyed.

So where did he get it?

Comment: I call *plot hole*. But he could have made one, right?

Comment: I didn't see anything that ruled out a second prototype. Also, did the MCU universe firmly say who designed the prototype?

Comment: If he could have made one, or you can come up with any logical explanation, it is, by definition [not a plot hole](http://imgur.com/gallery/L7zDu).

Comment: I am 100% positive

Comment: They'd found the broken parts. I'd assumed that he'd "glued" it back together and was trying to get it to work (as he learned how to make it work).

Answer (score 4):

Yondu had his standard one that was destroyed by Nebula, and the experimental one that was burned with his body.  So we know for a fact that Yondu has at least two, and possibly more that he's played with or hidden as emergency backups.  There are many different ways Kraglin could have gotten ahold of one of these.  Here are two that I think are very highly plausible:

1. Yondu left him one.  Kraglin was basically Yondu's best friend, it wouldn't be outside Yondu's character to have secretly left him one that Kraglin only got once Yondu died.
2. Kraglin found it in the ship.  The ship they end up in was a part of the larger ship, probably not used much.  It would make sense that Yondu hid one in here and might have forgotten about it.

Answer (score 0):

Rocket picked the broken parts of the arrow and they fixed it. Peter gave the arrow to Kraglin. Yondu had prototype and finished fin (which is smaller). You usually do not make prototype without plans, it is possible Yondu kept plans in the computer somewhere so they just fixed the one Nebula destroyed or made a new one.